# Template class woes; Proper template signature?

Tags: c++, templates

I am implementing a template class and I am not sure if I have the signatures correct. Below I've included a sample of my code, showing a couple of the situations I am concerned about:

mymap.h:

---

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename KEY, typename T>
class Map{
private:
    struct Elem {

    };

public:

    Map();
    // constructs empty Map

    Map(const Map &rhs);

    ~Map();

    Map& operator=(const Map &rhs);

    bool insert(KEY, T);

    T& operator[](KEY);

};

template<typename KEY, typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Map<KEY, T>&);

#include "mymap.cpp"

#endif
```

---

And now the .cpp file:

---

```
#include mymap.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Assingment Operator
template < typename KEY , typename T >
Map< KEY , T >& Map< KEY , T >::operator=(const Map &rhs){

    //Avoid self assignment
    if( this != &rhs ){

         //Snip
    }

    return *this;
}


//Insert, return true if successful.
template < typename KEY , typename T >
bool Map< KEY , T >::insert(KEY, T){

    //Snip
}
```

---

As you can see, and I'm sure you are all well aware, template signatures can get pretty messy from what I've read. Does this look correct, or do I have some blinding errors that are easily noticeable to a more practiced eye?

I know there are a million posts about templates, I've read a few guides about them but I still cannot find too much on this specific issue.

**Also, before the inevitable "get rid of using namespace std" comments appear, I include it for debugging and it *does* end up going away, I promise:)**

Thanks!

---

Edit: Sorry about the confusion, I seemed to have missed a very important part of my post... the errors!

I have about 5 of these, all with various line numbers:

```
mymap.cpp:41:1: error: ‘Map’ does not name a type
```

and an equal number of:

```
expected initializer before ‘<’ token
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear; is the question simply "does my code look correct?".  Or is there a specific compiler error or something that's troubling you?

Comment: The definition of member functions of a class template should be in the same header file that contains the class template definition

Comment: Concerning the code review task, maybe [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is the right place

Comment: @AndyProwl: They are: note the `#include` at the bottom.

Comment: The `.cpp` file shouldn't include the header! And it shouldn't be called `.cpp`, since that'll mess up any sane build environment. Popular names are `.tcc` or `.icc`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You have good eye, I didn't even notice that

Comment: Including `abusing namespace std;` *for debugging* seems like one of the Worst Ideas Ever...

Comment: I suppose "debugging" is a bad term. I meant I include it while I'm writing my code so I don't have to scope every time I cout until I get it working, then go back through with a find/replace.

Also, @OliCharlesworth I forgot to include my errors, sorry about that. I'm having issues with "Map does not name a type." I'm editing my post now.

Comment: @Joshua: You can use "using std::cout" instead of "using namespace std".

Comment: The struct Elem - it starts but doesn't end?

Comment: @user93353 That was a formatting error.

Comment: @Joshua That code would produce an error on the very first line of mymap.cpp.  `#include mymap.h` is not correct syntax.

Comment: @nobar you just improved my life by so much.

Comment: Do you have a semicolon at the end of struct Elem { }?

Comment: @user93353 sigh, yes.

Comment: ignoring the `#include mymap.h`, I get no errors when I compile the above.

Comment: @user93353 I compile the same thing: g++ -g mymap.cpp mymap.h test.cpp  (test.cpp is just a blank main file) and I get "Map does not name a type"

Comment: try `g++ -g mymap.cpp test.cpp`

Comment: Should close as duplicate: numerous questions related to putting template implementation s in .cpp instead of headers.

Comment: So your mymap.cpp #includes mymap.h which #includes mymap.cpp?

Comment: @AndyProwl No, it's not. codereview.SE is only for working code. Please don't send people to other sites if you're not familiar with their rules.

Comment: @svick: I just tried to give a direction, because the way it was originally stated, the question definitely did *not* fit SO. The OP was asking something like "Is what I am doing OK? Could you take a look?", which sounded more like a code review task than a request for help with a particular issue/obstacle/bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `#include mymap.h` from `mymap.cpp`

Then

```
#include "mymap.h"
```

in `test.cpp`

and compile it with

```
g++ -g test.cpp
```

For template classes, everything has to be in the header.

Comment: I had to do g++ -g test.cpp mymap.h but it worked, thanks a bunch for all your help.